# Разработка на codeignitor на локале и на хостинге

Tags: php, codeigniter

Добрый день! Экспериментирую с git и codeignitor 2, вобщем сделал "приложение" Hello World, на локальном сервере OpenServer всё отлично запускается http://joxi.ru/J2beG8BsLa8bm6 а вот тот же репозиторий на хостинге отдаёт 404 ошибку http://cockie.maler1988.tmweb.ru/ . Репозиторий обновил и синхронизировал http://joxi.ru/Drlae4Buk1MPmP но всравно не работает.

В config.php параметр base_url прописал как

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
```

я подумал что может быть ошибка из-за того что адрес локальной копии и копии на реальном хостинге отличаются. Но это ни к чему не привело.

В чём ещё может быть ошибка, непойму.

Вот листинг файлов .htaccess , там их два в папке /application/.htaccess такой:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

В папке /system/.htaccess такой:

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

Нужно их к единому виду приводить?

Answer (score 1):

Причин может быть много, но для начала посмотри, как у тебя .htaccess выглядит на хостинге (если там апач используется). 
Соль в том, чтобы заставить сервер все запросы направлять в файл index.php.

Кинь сюда листинг .htaccess

Comment: добавил листинг в тект вопроса

Comment: удалил эти два файла, создал в корне один .htaccess с таким содержаанем `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]` - не помогло =(